# Formato fechas html

Tags: html5, date, bootstrap-3

Verán en los formularios cuando utilizo el campo input type date, siempre que cambio de navegador cambia el formato a meses, días, años... pero necesito que sin importar el navegador se mantenga en días, meses, años

```html
<form action="" id="form">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="male">Monto a ingresar</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="inversion" placeholder="$10.000.000" class="form-control" id="separadorMiles" required><br>
            <label for="startDate">Fecha Inicio</label><br>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="dateIni"  value="2018-04-10" min="2016-04-27" max="2018-05-09" class="form-control" ><br>
            <label for="endDate">Fecha Terminación</label><br>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="dateFin"  value="2018-05-10" min="2016-04-28" max="2018-05-10"  class="form-control" ><br>
            <br>
            <button type="button" onclick="getData()" class="btn btn-default">Consultar</button>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app-60.js?110"></script>
            </div>
        </div>     
</form>
```

Comment: Que el valor de un input se represente de una manera u otra en el navegador, no quiere decir que ese sea el valor que tiene el campo (internamente el valor siempre va a ir yyyy-mm-dd). Intentar cambiarlo es posible, pero puede dar una mala experiencia de usuario (p.e. si fuerzas que sea dd/mm/yyyy, eso puede ser confuso para usuarios de Estados Unidos acostumbrados a mm/dd/yyyy).

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar un atributo `pattern` para dar formato a la fecha, pero solo se aplicara cuando hagas el post del dato.

```
pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"
```

Mas info haciendo clic [aca](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date) en la parte que dice *Manejo de compatibilidad entre navegadores*

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo tan simple como efectivo:

```js
        var d = new Date();

        var month = new Array(11);
        month[0] = "01";
        month[1] = "02";
        month[2] = "03";
        month[3] = "04";
        month[4] = "05";
        month[5] = "06";
        month[6] = "07";
        month[7] = "08";
        month[8] = "09";
        month[9] = "10";
        month[10] = "11";
        month[11] = "12";

        document.write(d.getDate() + '/' + month[d.getMonth()] + "/" + d.getFullYear());
```

Además creo que deberías cambiar el formato del `min` y `max`. Como te deja en un comentario otro compañero es posible que forzar el formato no resulte efectivo si tienes un público de diversos paises. En estre caso podrías si tienes identificado el origen de los usuarios poner algo así en tu código:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US'));

var options = { hour12: true };
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-GB', options));
```